# Difference between adding function to prototype and object literal in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

If I have a constructor `Quo`

```
var Quo = function (string) {
     this.status = string;
};
```

and then made a new object using `var myQuo = new Quo("confused");`

what would be the difference between:

```
Quo.get_status = function () { 
    return this.status;
};
```

and

```
Quo.prototype.get_status = function () { 
    return this.status;
};
```

Comment: This answer may help you out understanding constructor functions and prototype: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's suppose you have created `myQuo`, as you described

```
var myQuo = new Quo("confused");
```

If you define `get_status` as a property of `Quo`, then to get the status of `myQuo` you would have to call `Quo.get_status`.  However, `Quo.get_status` will need to know the object context (myQuo) to return the correct value of status.  You can redefine the function to accept the object as an argument as in the following:

```
Quo.get_status = function (quo) { 
  return quo.status;
};
var status = Quo.get_status(myQuo);
```

Alternatively, you could keep the function `Quo.get_status` as you wrote it in your question, but you will need to invoke the function in a manner that binds `myQuo` to "this":

```
Quo.get_status = function() {
  return this.status;
};
var status = Quo.get_status.call(myQuo);
```

Either solution is awkward.  The preferred solution is to take advantage of Javascript's prototype functionality and define `get_status` as a prototype function that will be locally accessible to all `Quo` objects, such as `myQuo`.

```
Quo.prototype.get_status = function () { 
  return this.status;
};
var status = myQuo.get_status();
```

Comment: This makes sense, my only confusion is when you call `Quo.get_status(myQuo);`. How can you pass in a argument `myQuo` if the function takes no parameters? Is this a mistake?

Comment: @oroscioli You can't actually, thanks for pointing that out, since I accidentally skimmed over that detail. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It seems the difference between static method and instance method in Java

Answer (score 22):

When you define a function, it has a property `prototype` that is used as the `[[prototype]]` of all of the objects it creates using the `new` keyword. When you add members to `Quo.prototype`, all objects created using `new Quo()` will be able to read the member as if they had it (through their `[[prototype]]`, namely `Quo.prototype`). On the other hand, if you assign members to `Quo` directly, you can only access them through `Quo` itself.

Example:

```
var Quo = function (status) {
    this.status = status;
}

Quo.status = "enlightened";

Quo.get_status = function() {
    return this.status;
}

Quo.prototype.get_status = function() {
    return this.status;
}

var quo = new Quo("confused");

Quo.get_status(); // "enlightened"
quo.get_status(); // "confused"
```