# Is not a function using prototype in js vanilla

Tags: javascript

This is my error, but I have some functions like that and they work. What am I doing wrong?

I try to change the prototype's name but it's the same error

```js
function Pendejo(nickname, edad, pendejo) {
  this.nickname = nickname;
  this.edad = edad;
  this.pendejo = pendejo;
}

Pendejo.prototype.show = function() {
  return `Soy ${this.nickname} y soy ${this.pendejo}% pendejo`;
}

let ryu = new Pendejo('Ryu', 22, 100);
console.log(Pendejo.show());
```

Comment: Do you mean ryu.show() ?

Comment: `ryu.show()`, not `Pendejo.show()`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between adding function to prototype and object literal in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724533/difference-between-adding-function-to-prototype-and-object-literal-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the function from the object `ryu`

```js
function Pendejo(nickname, edad, pendejo) {
  this.nickname = nickname;
  this.edad = edad;
  this.pendejo = pendejo;
}

Pendejo.prototype.show = function() {
  return `Soy ${this.nickname} y soy ${this.pendejo}% pendejo`;
}

let ryu = new Pendejo('Ryu', 22, 100);
console.log(ryu.show());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call show() on the object, not the function:

```js
function Pendejo(nickname, edad, pendejo) {
  this.nickname = nickname;
  this.edad = edad;
  this.pendejo = pendejo;
}

Pendejo.prototype.show = function() {
  return `Soy ${this.nickname} y soy ${this.pendejo}% pendejo`;
}

let ryu = new Pendejo('Ryu', 22, 100);
console.log(ryu.show());
```